# Отображение Navigationa Bar в Samsung Galaxy S8

Tags: android

Недавно начал разработку приложения на android. И возникает проблема с Samsung Galaxy S8, у которого есть возможность скрывать navigation bar. Как сделать так чтобы данная панель отображалась всегда?

Дошел вот до этого вопроса: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44884683/android-how-to-force-navigation-bar-to-be-visible-on-samsung-galaxy-s8. И понял по комментам, что можно просто скрыть кнопку скрывания и отображения нижней панели и все будет работать нормально. Панель всегда будет отображаться. Но так и не понял как этого добиться. Есть идеи?